# QtPositioning on Windows 8.1,

Tags: qt, gps, qml, gis, arcgis-runtime

I am working on a application using QML, QT Creator, and the Arcgis QML SDK. I am trying to get the application to find and read the GPS on windows 8.1 devices(Toughpad FZ-G1), but am struggling to find out how. My application will show a position based on the cell signal or network location, but will not use the GPS or that it is supported even with
  preferredPositioningMethods: PositionSource.SatellitePositioningMethods

The documentation states "Windows (with GPS receivers exposed as a serial port providing NMEA sentences" Does anyone know how to expose the GPS in this way or has done this in the past?
Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtpositioning-logfilepositionsource-example.html) is example how to get NMEA data from text file through C++ code. You can take it as example.

Comment: Or, if I understand your question, use [PositionSource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-positioning-qml.html#positionsource)